# How to call python functions from a flask instance and return values

Tags: python

here is what I need to do:
I have a python app with a Flask instance running on machine A and another python app running on machine B. The code on machine B shall call a url post request with a json like this:

```
response=requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_remote_data", json={"my_key":"my_value"})
```

The problem is that I don't know how to call a class method from the received route function and pass the parameter. This is my code on machine A:

```
from flask import Flask

class MyClass:
    def receive_and_return_values(self, incoming):
        return {"my_return_key":"my_return_value"}

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/get_remote_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_remote_data():
    my_json=request.get_json()
    #Here I want to call 'MyClass.receive_and_return_values' with the parameter 'my_json' and receive the return value.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5000)
```

Grateful for any advice

Comment: `MyClass().receive_and_return_values(my_json)`?

Comment: that's a static method why would u use class ?

Comment: My class has a lot of functions that receive and return values and I need to provide all of these methods as an API to the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an instance for my class on both machines and use it like this

```
import MyClass

@app.route('/get_remote_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_remote_data():
    my_json=request.get_json()
    receive_and_return_values(my_json)
```

if you want it to be the same object use a singleton design pattern,
of course the class should be in a separate file and import it.

Comment: I must be seriously stupid to miss that...

`my_class=MyClass()`

`my_class.receive_and_return_values(my_json)`